# change css using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to call a JS event, depending on a button press, (there are three buttons) i want some CSS to change the font-size (differently for each button), but what i have does not work. can anyone help?

```css
body {
     background-image: url("back2.jpg");
     background-size: 100% 100%;
 } 

 .buttonSize1{
    font-size: 3px;
 }
 
 .buttonsize2{
   font-size: 26px;
 }
 
 .buttonsize3{
   font-size: 45px;
 }
 
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    Top: 100px;
    Left: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    border: #0E6B5B 3px solid;
    background-color: #FF9933;
}

p {
    padding-left: 100px;
}
td {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    
}
.opac {
     opacity: 0.5;
     filter: alpha(opacity=10); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 } 
 
 .opac:hover {
     opacity: 1.0;
     filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 } 
 .MainTable{
     border: #0E6B5B 3px solid;
  background-color: #FF9933;
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 100px;
 padding-right: 100px;
 
 }
 
 table.center {
    width:70%; 
    margin-left:15%; 
    margin-right:15%;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="7Global.css"/>



<title> CSGO </title>

<script>

function textSizeS(){
document.getElementById("Maintbl").style.font-size = "3px";
}

function textSizeM(){
document.getElementById("Maintbl").style.font-size = "26px";
}

function textSizeL(){
document.getElementById("Maintbl").style.font-size = "45px";
}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<table class = "fixed opac">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="Index.html">Home</a> </td>
    
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><a href="3Maps.html">Maps</a> </td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="4CT.html">Counter <br/> Terrorists</a> </td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="5T.html">Terrorists</a> </td>
  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="6About.html">About</a> </td>
 
   </tr> 
   <tr>
    <td><button class="buttonsize1" onclick="textSizeS()">A</button> <button class= "buttonsize2" onclick="textSizeM()">A</button> <button class= "buttonsize3" onclick="textSizeL()">A</button></td>
 
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<table id = "Maintbl" class = "MainTable center">
  <td>  CS:GO’s Next Major </td>
  <tr>
    <td>
Europe Region – Hosted by DreamHack

 </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id = "Maintbl" class = "MainTable center">
<td> Operation Wildfi </td>
    <tr>
  <td>

What’s new? Visit the page below for details!
 </td>
  </tr>
</table>  

<table id = "Maintbl" class = "MainTable center">
<td>  We made some adjustments to rifles recently... </td>
    <tr>
  <td>
nCS:GO. M
 </td>
  </tr>
</table>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't re-use IDs...they have to be unique on each page.

Comment: ID's of what? the buttons?

Comment: The tables all have the same ID. "Maintbl"

Comment: Don't just dump your HTML like this - read [ask]

Comment: thanks, on:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp
it sais, Font-Size not FontSize, i removed the "-" and now it works!
thanks for the help.

Comment: also, i don't think i "dump'ed" the HTML, i just posted what i wrote and im sorry if its not professorial but i am just starting JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, where I added a wrapper div to set the font size to, corrected the syntax error from `...style.font-size` to `...style.fontSize` and removed that duplicated id's (as they should be unique).

```js
function textSizeS(){
  document.getElementById("MaintblWrapper").style.fontSize = "3px";
}

function textSizeM(){
  document.getElementById("MaintblWrapper").style.fontSize = "26px";
}

function textSizeL(){
  document.getElementById("MaintblWrapper").style.fontSize = "45px";
}
```

```css
body {
     background-image: url("back2.jpg");
     background-size: 100% 100%;
 } 

 .buttonSize1{
    font-size: 3px;
 }
 
 .buttonsize2{
   font-size: 26px;
 }
 
 .buttonsize3{
   font-size: 45px;
 }
 
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    Top: 100px;
    Left: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    border: #0E6B5B 3px solid;
    background-color: #FF9933;
}

p {
    padding-left: 100px;
}
td {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    
}
.opac {
     opacity: 0.5;
     filter: alpha(opacity=10); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 } 
 
 .opac:hover {
     opacity: 1.0;
     filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 } 
 .MainTable{
     border: #0E6B5B 3px solid;
  background-color: #FF9933;
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 100px;
 padding-right: 100px;
 
 }
 
 table.center {
    width:70%; 
    margin-left:15%; 
    margin-right:15%;
  }
```

```html
<table class = "fixed opac">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="Index.html">Home</a> </td>
    
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><a href="3Maps.html">Maps</a> </td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="4CT.html">Counter <br/> Terrorists</a> </td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="5T.html">Terrorists</a> </td>
  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="6About.html">About</a> </td>
 
   </tr> 
   <tr>
    <td><button class="buttonsize1" onclick="textSizeS()">A</button> <button class= "buttonsize2" onclick="textSizeM()">A</button> <button class= "buttonsize3" onclick="textSizeL()">A</button></td>
 
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<div id = "MaintblWrapper">
  
  <table class = "MainTable center">
    <td>  CS:GO’s Next Major </td>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Europe Region – Hosted by DreamHack

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table class = "MainTable center">
    <td> Operation Wildfi </td>
    <tr>
      <td>

        What’s new? Visit the page below for details!
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>  

  <table class = "MainTable center">
    <td>  We made some adjustments to rifles recently... </td>
    <tr>
      <td>
        nCS:GO. M
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>  

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`fontSize` not `font-size`

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/eLrdeagq/

```
function textSizeS(){
document.getElementById("Maintbl").style.fontSize  = "3px";
}
```